# Why can't I use key space in gdb environment?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, gdb

When I try to hit space key it won't work in gdb.
Even when I try copy paste from other session the key characters are being clipped.

Answer (score 0):

ok, got it,
in ~/.inputrc I had to remove Space: magic-space feature